# How can I find all the matches of two sorted arrays in O(n) with limitations on number of comparisons?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, divide-and-conquer

I have two arrays. Array A contains n elements, array B contains m elements, and m < n. They are sorted in ascending order. I want to find all the matches between the two arrays. Two adjacent elements in array A may correspond to the same element of array B.

There are two constraints:

1. The algorithm should have a time complexity of O(n)
2. I can only compare each element in A a limited number of times with values in B: at most ceil(log(n)) times. This means at most one binary search can be performed per value in A.

To compare the elements, I need to use a `compare` function that runs in O(1). This function can have three different return values:

1. if the two given values match, or
2. the first is less than the second, or
3. the first is greater than the second.

So we cannot simply merge the two arrays.

How can I finish this in O(n) time?

I have tried the following ways:

1. Compare each element of these two arrays from beginning to the end. However, if all of A's elements match B's last element we will exceed the compare time limitation of ceil(log(n)).
2. Pick the middle element of A, binary search it in B, and then split the B array into 2 partitions. If we do not consider the worst situation, the overall time complexity is determined by

   ```
    T(n) = 2T(n/2) + logm,
   ```

   ...which is OK. However, in the worst case, all of A's elements correspond to the minimum or maximum element in B, and then the time complexity is determined by

   ```
    T(n) = 2T(n/2) + logm,
   ```

   ...which is not O(n).

I am out of other ideas. How can I design this algorithm with the given constraints? Or maybe I have a mistake in how I calculated the time complexity?

Comment: It's called 'Merge Join'

Comment: @MitchWheat Merge join is not working, the "match" does not simply mean they are equal. "To caompare the elements, there is a function runs in O(1), tell the function the elements in A and B, it will return if they match, higher or lower. So we cannot simply merge the two arrays."

Comment: A match is a match, O(1) is constant time. So Merge Join

Comment: @MitchWheat, sorry, I still not understand how it works, can you give any further explanation?

Comment: What is `m` in `T(n) = 2T(n/2) + logm`?

Comment: If all the array elements are the same, then there are O(n^2) matches.  How do you expect to "find" all of these in O(n) time?

Comment: @trincot m is the length of array B (n is the length of array A), which is not a constant number and we only know that n < m

Comment: Please correct the question then, because you wrote there *"Each contains n elements."*.

Comment: @trincot you are right, I have corrected it, thank you for remind me

Answer (score 0):

```
public static List<Integer> findMatchedElements(int[] arr1, int[] arr2) {
        List<Integer> matchedElements= new ArrayList<>();
        int i = 0; // Pointer for arr1
        int j = 0; // Pointer for arr2
        
        while (i < arr1.length && j < arr2.length) {
            if (arr1[i] == arr2[j]) {
                matchedElements.add(arr1[i]);
                i++;
                j++;
            } else if (arr1[i] < arr2[j]) {
                i++;
            } else {
                j++;
            }
        }
        
        return matchedElements;
    }
```

Comment: This is the first trying I did, it will exceed the limitation of compare. If all the A's element corresponds to the last element of B, in this algo, index i will stay in 0, and A[0] will compare with B[0], B[1],...B[n], exceed the ceil(logn) times. For each A's element, we can only call the match function ceil(logn) times.

Comment: the issue you've mentioned, you can make use of binary search in the second array to ensure that each element from the first array is compared only once.

Comment: if I use binary search for each element from the first array, I will need to call the march function ceil(logn) times, but in total, it will call the function nlogn times.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
public static List<Integer> findMatchedElements(int[] arr1, int[] arr2) {
    List<Integer> matchedElements = new ArrayList<>();
    int i = 0; // Pointer for arr1
    int j = 0; // Pointer for arr2

    while (i < arr1.length && j < arr2.length) {
        if (arr1[i] == arr2[j]) {
            matchedElements.add(arr1[i]);
            i++;
            j++;
        } else if (arr1[i] < arr2[j]) {
            i++;
        } else {
            // Use binary search to find the next greater or equal element in arr2
            int searchResult = binarySearch(arr2, arr1[i], j, arr2.length - 1);
            if (searchResult != -1) {
                j = searchResult;
            } else {
                break; // No need to continue, no more matches possible
            }
        }
    }

    return matchedElements;
}

private static int binarySearch(int[] arr2, int target, int left, int right) {
    while (left <= right) {
        int mid = left + (right - left) / 2;
        if (arr2[mid] == target) {
            return mid;
        } else if (arr2[mid] < target) {
            left = mid + 1;
        } else {
            right = mid - 1;
        }
    }
    // If no exact match found, return the index of the next greater element
    if (left < arr2.length) {
        return left;
    }
    return -1; // No greater or equal element found
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a normal binary search for finding all matches you use an algorithm corresponding to binary search in an infinite array, so after matching A[i] with B[j] you don't perform a normal binary search in B, but instead compare A[i] with B[j+1], B[j+2], B[j+4], B[j+8], B[j+16], etc until you get hit (or run into the end of the array) and then you do a normal binary search based on that result and skip ahead in B.

That keeps the overall time to O(n) and doesn't need more than O(log n) searches per element in A.

(Could add detailed algorithm later.)

Comment: That makes sense!

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. Can you help me to prove the time complexity of O(n), I feel there is still some part of the array B have been recalculated and are ignorantly small, how can I prove the algo is in linear time.